# Is there an alternative function for wait() in Java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, game-development

I am currently creating a Pokemon-like game for one of my projects. I have three buttons; attack, run, and magic. When I click any of the buttons, I want it to implement its respective function (e.g. when I click the attack button, it will attack the enemy) and then pause for a few seconds, then the enemy will be the one to attack after the user's turn. How do I do that?

Comment: There is a Sleep() in Thread class. It will work but I would say Using handler with postDalayed() is cleaner and will give you more control.

Answer (score 1):

Use handler

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    //Do your functions
}
}, 1000// your delay time);
```